# How to input many vertex to geometry shader, Buffers and shaders pass data to each other?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I want do a bokeh app on Android, use OpenGL ES 3.0, I read this article [How To Fake Bokeh](https://therealmjp.github.io/posts/bokeh/):

> 1. Do a full-res bokeh point extraction pass. For each pixel, compute the average brightness of the 5x5 block surrounding the pixel and
>    compare it with the brightness of the current pixel. If the pixel
>    brightness minus the average brightness is above a certain threshold
>    and the CoC size is above a certain threshold, **push the pixel
>    position + color + CoC size onto an append buffer and output a value
>    of 0.0 as the pixel color**. If it doesn’t pass the threshold, output
>    the input color.
> 2. Do a regular DOF pass. I implemented two versions: one that does a
>    full-res disc-based blur in two passes using 16 samples on a Poisson
>    disc with radius == CoC size, and one that does ye olde 1/4-res
>    Gaussian blur (with edge bleeding reduction) and a full-screen lerp
>    between the un-blurred and blurred version.
> 3. **Copy the embedded count from the append buffer to another buffer,
>    and use the second buffer as an indirect arguments buffer for a
>    DrawInstancedIndirect call. Basically this lets us draw however many
>    points are in the buffer, without having to copy anything back to
>    the CPU. The vertex shader for each point then samples the
>    position/color/CoC size from the append buffer and passes it to the
>    geometry shader, which expands the point into a quad with size equal
>    to the CoC size**. The pixel shader then samples from a texture
>    containing the aperture shape, and additively blends the result into
>    an empty render target. The render target can be either full res, or
>    1/4 res to save on bandwidth.

Because I don't know much about OpengL ES, I don't know how to implement above bold, How does Java push the results of the fragment shader to the buffer and the contents of the buffer to the geometry shader? Can you give me some demo or example?

Comment: ES 3.0 cannot do most of that. There are no SSBOs or atomics in ES 3.0, nor is there a geometry shader. There may be extensions to that, but pure ES 3.0 cannot handle those things. ES 3.1 has SSBOs and atomics, and ES 3.2 has GS's.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks, I see most phones support 3.2, so I set up new version. But how to push the position in ssBO to the vertex shader?  Can you give me some sample or demo

Comment: Generating a quad per pixel is going to have horrible performance on mobile, doubly so if you are using geometry shaders to generate them. What's wrong with a simple array of points and using point size directly - why do you need to expand to a quad?

Comment: "The render target can 1/4 res to save on bandwidth." Just note that the geometry bandwidth of this approach will utterly dwarf the cost of your framebuffer color attachment, so the saving is from geometry reduction not framebuffer resolution ...